# Set image in UICollectionViewCell with af_setImageWithURL cost to much memory

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, alamofireimage

I have some memory issue using AFI. I have `UICollectionView` with custom cell, and each cell has a `UIImageView`. In `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, I set that image with `af_setImageWithURL`.

The problem is memory usage getting so high. If I set cell's image with local image, it only use 27Mb memory. But when I fetch image with `af_setImageWithURL`, memory usage are going about 87Mb.

So am I doing some mistake?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Documentation for setImageWithURL](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h),

It cached image locally, So it will keep your image in cache memory for reusability as tableView or collectionview reuse the cell, so it will not download image everytime and can use from cache memory.

So, It may take more memory because of cache i think!